# python sort list of lists with casting

Tags: python, sorting

I know tat similar questions has been asked already several times. And i do now how to use the search function, but it still does not work.

So here is the problem setup. I have a list of lists containing strings. One column contains strings which actually represent float values. And it is also the column i want to sort by. The problem is, that python seems to ignore the - (minus) sign on entries. So an example list of:

```
[[blaa, '0.3', bli], [bla, '0.1', blub], [bla, '-0.2', blub]]
```

gets sorted like this:

```
[[bla, '0.1', blub], [bla, '-0.2', blub], [blaa, '0.3', bli]]
```

and not how it should be:

```
[[bla, '-0.2', blub],[bla, '0.1', blub], [blaa, '0.3', bli]]
```

So far i have tried:

- casting the second column to float
  and sorting by that column

like:

```
for i in mylist:
  i[1] = float(i[1])    

mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

or with

```
for i in mylist:
  i[1] = float(i[1]) 

mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

- I also tried to define my own compare
  function:

like:

```
mylist.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(float(x), float(y)), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

And any other combination of the above methods, also the same with `sorted`. So far with no success, the minus sign gets ignored every time. How do is solve this?

**[edit]**
Also already tried the Ignacio suggestion. I should mention i HAVE to use python 2.5 .

Comment: So that might be the environmental issues. Check your python version.

Comment: If you mean for something to be strings, you should really put quotes around it as a consideration to people that might want to run your code.

Comment: How certain are you that they're all strings?

Comment: @aaronasterling: The OP should probably ask follow up questions instead of posting more code.

Comment: @Georg Good call. Comment rescinded.

Comment: Please don't use the word "cast".  The concept does not apply to Python.

Comment: @S.Lott, "cast" is a perfectly cromulent word.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
l = [["blaa", "0.3", "bli"], ["bla", "0.1", "blub"], ["bla", "-0.2", "blub"]]

l.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1]))

>>> [['bla', '-0.2', 'blub'], ['bla', '0.1', 'blub'], ['blaa', '0.3', 'bli']]
```

Comment: also tried that with now effect, just forget to mention it in the post above

Comment: @JohnMachin, presumably he was only looking at the final output (a graph, a text file, whatever) and not in the REPL of Python. Give the guy a break.

Answer (score 2):

Mine works fine, Python 3.1.2:

```
>>> l=[['', '0.3', ''], ['', '0.1', ''], ['', '-0.2', '']]
>>> sorted(l,key=lambda x:float(x[1]))
[['', '-0.2', ''], ['', '0.1', ''], ['', '0.3', '']]
```

and 2.6.5:

```
>>> l=[['', '0.3', ''], ['', '0.1', ''], ['', '-0.2', '']]
>>> sorted(l,key=lambda x:float(x[1]))
[['', '-0.2', ''], ['', '0.1', ''], ['', '0.3', '']]
```

Comment: there is now cast to float, i have a list of lists of strings

Comment: @inf.ig.sh: If even turning them to float then sort failed. Must be somewhere else goes wrong, not the sort function.